# Moverio BT-35E can't open a WebView

Tags: android-studio, android-webview, epson-moverio

I've started to program an app in Android Studio and I downloaded Moverio SDK and sample from here: https://tech.moverio.epson.com/en/bt-35e/developers_guide/developing_android_apps.html#ac2-3-2

I'm able to set the glasses resolution and all the other stuff described in the doc, in short:
using a SurfaceView I can see a video preview on the device that come from glasses camera.

What I need to do is to use the glasses camera in a WebView that load an html page with AR javascript lib.

I've tried in a easy way to make it with ionic and all works great except that I can't setup camera resolution..

this is my code, I hope someone can help me. Thank you

```
//SetupActivity.java

package io.ionic.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.epson.moverio.hardware.camera.CameraDevice;
import com.epson.moverio.hardware.camera.CameraManager;
import com.epson.moverio.hardware.camera.CameraProperty;
import com.epson.moverio.hardware.camera.CaptureDataCallback;
import com.epson.moverio.hardware.camera.CaptureStateCallback;
import com.epson.moverio.util.PermissionHelper;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

  private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

  private CameraManager mCameraManager = null;
  private CameraDevice mCameraDevice = null;
  private SurfaceView mSurfaceView = null;


  private PermissionHelper mPermissionHelper = null;
  private TextView mTextView_captureRate = null;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    mPermissionHelper = new PermissionHelper(this);
    mCameraManager = new CameraManager(this);



  }

  private CaptureStateCallback mCaptureStateCallback = null;
  private CaptureDataCallback mCaptureDataCallback = null;

  private TimerTask mTimerTask = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
      mHandler.post( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          if(null != mTextView_captureRate) mTextView_captureRate.setText(String.valueOf(mFps) + "[fps]");
          else ;
        }
      });
    }
  };
  private Timer mTimer   = null;
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  private float mFps = 0;

  private final Handler handler = new Handler();

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);



    mTimer = new Timer(true);
    mTimer.schedule( mTimerTask, 1000, 1000);

    //mTextView_captureRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_rate);
    String launchUrl = "";
    WebView Webv = null;

    try {
      mCaptureStateCallback = new CaptureStateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureStarted() {
         mCameraDevice.startPreview();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureStopped() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewStarted() {
          //setContentView(R.layout.activity_testo);
          // Load and use views afterwards

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewStopped() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRecordStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRecordStopped() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPictureCompleted() {

        }

      };
      mCameraDevice = mCameraManager.open(mCaptureStateCallback, null, mSurfaceView.getHolder());


      CameraProperty property = mCameraDevice.getProperty();
      property.setExposureMode(CameraProperty.EXPOSURE_MODE_MANUAL);
      property.setExposureStep(5);
      property.setCaptureSize(1920, 1080);
      property.setCaptureFps(30);
      mCameraDevice.setProperty(property);
      //mCameraDevice.startCapture();
      mCameraDevice.startCapture();

      TextView sample = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      if(null != mCameraDevice){

        if(null != property){
          String str = "";
          str += "Size         : " + property.getCaptureSize()[0] + "x" + property.getCaptureSize()[1] + " / " + property.getCaptureFps() + " [fps] ";
          str += "Exposure     : " + (property.getExposureMode().equals(CameraProperty.EXPOSURE_MODE_AUTO) ? property.getExposureMode() + "(" + property.getExposureStep() + ")" : property.getExposureStep()) + " ";
          str += "Brightness   : " + property.getBrightness() + " ";
          str += "Sharpness    : " + property.getSharpness() + " ";
          //str += "Whitebalance : " + (property.getWhiteBalanceMode().equals(CameraProperty.WHITE_BALANCE_MODE_AUTO) ? property.getWhiteBalanceMode() + "(" + property.getWhiteBalanceTemperature() + ")"  : property.getWhiteBalanceTemperature()) + "\n";
          //str += "PowerLineFrequency : " + property.getPowerLineFrequencyControlMode() + "\n";
          str += "CaptureDataFormat ： " + property.getCaptureDataFormat() + "\n";
          sample.setText(str);
        }
        else {
          sample.setText("null");
        }
      }
     
      //sample.setText("Hello");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestart()    {
    super.onRestart();

    if(null != mCameraDevice) {
      mCameraDevice.stopCapture();
    } else;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    if(null != mCameraDevice) {
      mCameraDevice.stopCapture();

    } else ;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(null != mCameraDevice) {
      mCameraDevice.stopCapture();
      mCameraManager.close(mCameraDevice);
    } else;

    mTimer.cancel();
    mTimer = null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    mPermissionHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }
}
```

and this is the xml

```
<!---activity_setup.xml-->


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SetupActivity">

  <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="965dp"
    android:layout_height="541dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.161" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="943dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="Prova"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.157"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: **update** now I'm able to launch the webview after the setup of glasses camera but unfortunately the camera used in webview is not that..

Comment: i tried other solutions but i still have the same problem, is there anyone who can help me?